# Was Loki's spear manipulating the Avengers?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-avengers, marvel-cinematic-universe

While the entire group was on the heli-carrier (or whatever it's called) everyone was in Banner and Stark's lab, and they began arguing, some making rather uncharacteristic remarks.  The fight somewhat ends when Banner picks up Loki's spear.

Having re-watched the movie last night, it seems to me that perhaps Loki was acting through the spear to influence the Avengers.  Is this the case?  Is there anything to support this?

Comment: The spear has the mind gem in it

Comment: I thought that's what this scene was implying all along.

Comment: @Huangism The spear MIGHT have an Infinity Stone in it, which MIGHT be the Mind Gem. This is all (admitedly extremely likely) guess work until we know more.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Right? I thought this was evident.

Comment: @DrRDizzle - Well the Scepter DID turn out to be the Mind gem....

Answer (score 19):

By listening to the Director's commentary in the Blu-ray, the idea is that Loki's scepter does not only affect people, controlling them by touch (as with Barton/Hawkeye) but the mere presence of it can create confusion and insert anger into people's hearts around it, at least in the near proximity of the scepter.

The shot where the camera flips and everybody is upside-down behind the scepter is to indicate that it is turning everybody not evil, but at least angry and "out of character".  Banner and Stark are the ones that spend more time around it in the lab, but they are also the more intelligent and reasonable so, the scepter affects them more slowly, but in the case of Natasha, Fury and Rogers, they become angry very easily.

Anyway, the one taking the scepter is Banner, cause he's the one with the rage problems, thus, the one the scepter has more power over once he lets the anger flow when he starts arguing with the others, the scepter appears to give him direct "commands" without him noticing it, indicating that the people under it's effect are not turned evil, but are under mental control. That's why when he becomes Hulk he goes berserk, he's not evil, but the influence of the scepter has turned him angry beyond reason.

Comment: This is a good account of the events of the film and the Sceptre's implicit work on the Avengers.